# Add Show User Link to Navbar Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, show

In a class, I'm built a Pintrest style app, and I recently set up a show action for my users.  The link works fine on the individual pins, but when I try to add the `users#show` link to the Navbar called "Profile" it does not navigate anywhere. The Profile link should navigate to `users#show`, but the URL is showing for Profile is my `pins#index` which is my root route.  Here are the links in my Navbar under `_header.html.erb`.

```
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Add Trip", new_pin_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", @user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "About", about_path%></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Here is my `users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @pins = @user.pins.page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
  end
end
```

But the show user link on the pins in `_pin.html.erb` which is rendered in my `pins#index` works fine.

```
<div class="box">
  <p class= "description">
    <%= pin.description %>
  </p>
  <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image(:medium)), pin %>
  <p class= "author">
    <strong>
      Posted by <%= link_to pin.user.name, pin.user %>
    </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Lastly, if I copy the same link that is in `_pin.html.erb` `<%= link_to pin.user.name, pin.user %>` to the Navbar, I get `undefined local variable or method`pin' for #<#:0x00000100c82520>`.

Here is my `routes.rb` incase that helps.

```
devise_for :users
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `current_user` instead of `@user`, since `@user` will be nil in most cases (except on your users#show page.

It might also be a good idea to create a `/profile` route that always loads the current user.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I think I saw where I was getting confused, I thought I could call @user to route to the show, instead of calling it on the show page. Is there a reason that `current_user` didn't show up as an option when I did Rake Routes in my Terminal?

Also, thanks for the tip, I'll take a look and see if I can find how to create the `/profile` route.

Comment: Great, I wish i had found your response earlier :)